# R и машинное обучение

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, r

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой пакет лучше использовать для следующей задачи:
есть 10 цифр - допустим это номер телефона(token). Примерно 150 млн. телефонных номеров, каждый помечен как 0  или 1, допустим плохой и хороший. Это тренировочный набор.

Хочу натренировать нейронку так, чтобы получая новый телефон, не из тренировочного набора, нейронная сеть предсказывала вероятность 0 или 1 для нового телефона.
Загоняю данные в пакет neuralnet:

`nn <- neuralnet(good ~ token, data=train_data ,hidden = 10,  linear.output=F)`

`res.z <- predict(nn, test_data)`

res.z для любого телефона всегда имеет одинаковую вероятность равную 0.66.

Нужно поменять настройки или другую нейронку использовать?

Comment: И вы никак эти номера не обрабатываете, подаёте в нейросеть как есть? И чему вы хотите нейросеть обучить в таком случае - просто запоминанию "плохих" номеров? 150 миллионов данных запихать в 10 нейронов?

Comment: И лучше начать не с нейронок, а с простых моделей типа логистической регрессии. Единственное, что мне кажется можно извлечь из телефонных номеров - это код страны и код региона. Какие-то страны и регионы могут оказаться более сдвинуты в сторону 0 или 1. А в целом мне кажется это бесполезная затея.

Comment: Я пытался в z-нормализацию и min-max scaling, но результат не меняется. Регрессия не деёт нужных результатов. У меня есть описанный тренировочный набор, я хочу в нейронку подавать например ещё 15 млн. цифр, чтобы она предсказала для каждой это будет 0 или 1. И, допустим 5 млн, с вероятностью 1 менее 0.5  из массива вычистить.

Comment: И никакая модель не даст вам никаких результатов. Я так понимаю, у вас соотношение единиц к нулям в ваших данных 2:1, и любая модель вам кроме вероятности 2/3 ничего больше не выдаст. Хоть нейросеть, хоть LR, хоть бустинг какой. В ваших данных просто нет сигнала, лучшее, что может сделать любая модель в таких условиях - это выдавать для любых входных данных среднюю вероятность таргета из обучающей выборки.

Comment: соотношение 1 к 0 в тренировочном наборе 1 на 1000 примерно, так что сигнал там есть.

Comment: Тогда не понимаю, как получается константная вероятность 0.66 на выходе )

Comment: а сам признак «0/1» имеет хоть какую-то связь с содержимым? ну, типа `1=красивый-номер, 0=некрасивый` или хотя бы `1=корректный, 0=некорректный`. если нет, и «0/1» — это, например, «спамер/не-спамер», то будет гадание на кофейной гуще, и лучше обратиться к профессионалам в этом деле, а не к примитивной вычислительной технике.

Comment: Да, признак имеет смысл, это результат работы номера. 0 - нет результата 1 - есть результат от этого номера. Все номера создавались случайно и полностью рандомизировано, потом каждый номер тестировался на наличие результата. Некоторые номера на наличие результата не тестировались, у них тоже 0.

Comment: Номера с результатом 0 могли дублироваться и проверятся на наличие результата несколько раз. Номера с результатом 1 уникальные.

Comment: *Да, признак имеет смысл, это результат работы номера. 0 - нет результата 1 - есть результат от этого номера.* — т.е., никакой связи между цифрами, составляющими номер, и «пометкой» 0/1, не имеется. да, это классическое гадание на кофейной гуще. ну или по звёздам. компьютер тут бессилен.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Но всё же можно было бы попытаться - выделить из номера регион, разбить на отдельные цифры, попытаться выделить "красивые номера" и кластеры похожих номеров - и уже с этими признаками попытаться что-то сделать. У меня лично претензия к автору вопроса только в том, что он не хочет делать никакие признаки руками, а на целом номере никакая нейросеть, понятное дело, работать не будет.

Comment: Регион и код оператора я выделял, компьютеру в этом случае не хватает 32gb оперативной памяти для расчётов. Если смотреть на нейронки с точки зрения распознавания образов, там 0 и 1 тоже никакой связи между цифрами, которыми представлены параметры каждого пикселя изображения, не имеется. Но, тем не менее, при наличии хорошего датасета связь устанавливается.

Comment: @Mike Нейросети, которые работают чисто с пикселями неэффективны. Под каждую задачу нужен свой вид нейронов и своя топология нейросети. Для картинок очень хороши Convolution Layers, коорые "выделяют" из картинки разные признаки - границы изображения, например, ну, там много всего. Для чисто числовых данных нейросети не сильно полезны. Если у вас в память упирается, лучше попробуйте методы попроще, которые не требуют много памяти, начиная от Naive Bayes, И можете пробовать на части датасета, а не сразу на целом, если в память упирается.

Comment: @CrazyElf подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошие модули для Баеса в R. Лучше для иерархического.

Comment: @CrazyElf вполне эффективны пиксельные нейронки, я успешно развлекался с нейронкой, которая любую картинку схлопывает в 27 пикселей и потом 27-ю нейронами решает собака на картинке была изображена или нет. 1 с вероятностью выше 0.9 вылезало, если собака. При тренировочном наборе менее 10000 картинок.

Comment: @Mike Я про `R` ничего не знаю, только про `Python`, увы. А что касается собак - ну, смотря какой набор картинок. Если собака в произвольном месте картинки может быть, с произвольным сдвигом и поворотом и произвольного цвета, произвольной контрастности, то без CNN тут никак вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, с произвольным сдвигом и поворотом и произвольного цвета определяло с вероятностью выше 0.9